# iOS drawInRect memory leak - ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting, drawinrect

I've searched all over the internet and I have found alot of people with the same issue as me and no solution...

If I have something like an NSTimer and have it loop over and over and I stick this code in it for some reason I get massive memory leaks and the app crashes after about 100 or so loops.

But I have ARC enabled.

The memory issue is definitely win `drawInRect` according to instruments.

```
-(void)nstimerTick {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(testView.frame.size, NO, 0.0);

    [[testView image] drawInRect:testView.bounds];

    testView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't calling [`UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsEndImageContext) at the end of your method. You should.

Comment: +1 to you for thinking the same thought as me at the same time.

Comment: Ha! This was a pretty obvious one.

Comment: @KurtRevis, well I feel embarrassed... haha!